# Determine if cuda device in use?

Tags: cuda, cupy

**Is there a way to directly test whether a cuda device is currently in use by any kernels?**

I have a background thread that launches "raw" cuda kernels at full occupancy for a fractal program. The thread builds up large image arrays that I then want to let the user smoothly pan, rotate and zoom.

My GUI thread would like to use the GPU if it is not currently in use for the large image transformations since this runs at 100 fps. If the GPU is in use I can fall back to using CPU code instead at 10-20 fps.

If the GUI-thread GPU code is used when a background thread kernel is already running then the GUI-thread will freeze noticeably until the background kernel finishes. This freezing is what I'm seeking to eliminate by switching instead to CPU code for those frames. I've looked into interrupting the background kernel but solutions I've seen that do this add computational cost to the kernel and/or reset the context, both of which seem like overkill.

Is there a way to directly (asynchronously) detect whether the GPU is in use (by any kernel)? I suppose the GPU is always technically in use as a 2-D display driver, so excluding that activity of course.

My workaround would be to have a flag in my program which keeps track of whether all the kernels have completed. I would need to pass that flag between the two host threads and between the most nested objects within Model and View in my program. I started writing this and thought it was a bit of a messy solution and even then not always 100% accurate. So I wondered if there was a better way and in particular if the GPU could be tested directly at the point in the GUI thread that the decision is needed on whether to use GPU or CPU code for the next frame.

I'm using python 3.7, with cupy to access the GPU, but I would be willing to try to adapt a C++ solution.

I've looked in the docs, but with only basic knowledge of cuda it feels like looking for a needle in a haystack:
https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__DEVICE.html#group__CUDART__DEVICE

Comment: with some management of the usage of cuda streams, you might be able to use [`cudaStreamQuery()`](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__STREAM.html#group__CUDART__STREAM_1g2021adeb17905c7ec2a3c1bf125c5435).  A [casual glance](https://docs.cupy.dev/en/stable/reference/generated/cupy.cuda.Stream.html) suggests that the `done` attribute is how this is implemented in  `cupy` but I don't have a full solution for you.

Comment: also, I feel compelled to point out that if you are operating in a fully asynchronous wild-west environment, where you have independent asynchronous work submitters, you could sample the state of the GPU, discover it is idle, and then a nanosecond later another work submitter could submit something to that GPU.  So I'm skeptical that this asynchronous sampling method is a robust technique.

Comment: @RobertCrovella the first suggestion looks promising. I'll try it and comment again later. I'm only using the default steam so should be simple enough.

Comment: On the second suggestion, Are you saying to start a new python thread for the nanosecond kernel? Then have that thread emit an event that updates a gpu_available flag to True in the main thread if the kernel run successfully in a short space of time? The nanosecond kernel, even if run in a separate stream, would not run of course if the GPU is occupied since my main kernels are running with full occupancy.

Comment: I'm not sure we'll sort this out in the space of the comments.  You have a GUI thread and a background thread.  Suppose the GUI thread checks the `done` attribute and finds the null stream "idle".  Now suppose **at the same time** the background thread is getting ready to submit a kernel (i.e. a `cupy` function).  By the time the GUI thread, which thinks the GPU is idle, gets around to submitting its `cupy` function, the GPU is no longer idle due to the work just submitted by the background thread.  This looks like a race condition to me.  Do as you wish, of course.

Comment: You might also be able to use stream priority to get the GUI kernel to work its way through even if a background kernel is running, but this would probably depend on a number of kernel characteristics which are not possible to deduce from your question, and this doesn't appear to be  exposed in cupy. An alternative approach would be to get some control over the work submission. Create a wrapper work submission function, which 1. acquires global lock  2. launches work  3. launch callback to release global lock. If you can acquire the global lock from the GUI thread, launch there. Else, use CPU.

Comment: Thank you for your help with this. For this specific code, as it turns out the race condition will not be a problem. When the user presses the mouse to start a pan, rotate or zoom the first thing the code does is to **request** the background thread to stop. The GUI code just needs to know if it actually **has** stopped or not. The background thread won't restart until the mouse is released and a new fractal is requested to be generated by the background thread. Also it's not fatal if there's a freeze on the GUI, it's merely unpleasant.

Comment: Re steam priority, from what I've read I believe you need two conditions to be satisfied to have kernel concurrency on the GPU: 1) Separate non-blocking steams 2) Spare occupancy for the second kernel. The second condition is not satisfied because my top priority is that the fractal generation runs as fast as possible. I think cupy would support this but only by using separate python threads as well as separate steams. That's my reading of it but you never know for sure until you code it of course!

Comment: I have created a pair of wrapper work submission objects. Manager in the GUI thread passing Jobs to Worker in the background thread which manages it's own Job queue. These are both part of Model in my MVC design. Potentially I should be exposing Manager to View also so it can request the GPU work from Worker so that all the GPU work is done in one place. Or as you say, get the lock and then run it away from Worker, which is probably simpler since I actually want the GUI thread to wait until it's done in this case.

Comment: @RobertCrovella the done attribute method you first describes works :)

Comment: @RobertCrovella If you'd like to write that as an answer then I'd be happy to mark it as accepted. I suppose the only time it wouldn't work for someone is if a program was using multiple streams so you might want to caveat it. But for most simple cases like mine that just use the default stream, it's an elegant solution. I'll now go away and ponder the rest of what you said. Thanks again.

Comment: writing a comprehensible answer for me would involve inventing a test case out of whole cloth.  I'm unlikely to do that.  If you can hack together an example of what you did, and post it as an answer, I think that will be far more useful for future readers.   And I would most likely up-vote it.  Just a suggestion.  I think its doubtful that I would post an answer to this question anytime soon.

Comment: That's fine. I just wanted to give you the opportunity.

Answer (score 1):

This is the solution I used following help from @RobertCrovella.

```
import cupy as cp

stream_done: bool = cp.cuda.get_current_stream().done

if stream_done or worker_ready:
    # use cupy to draw next frame
else:
    # use numpy to draw next frame
```

Where worker_ready is a bool passed from the background worker GPU thread indicating it's activity.

For stream_done, see the [docs](https://docs.cupy.dev/en/stable/reference/generated/cupy.cuda.Stream.html). In my program I'm only using 1 cuda stream, the (unspecified) default stream. Otherwise I imagine you would need to test each stream depending on the problem.

After a lot of testing I found that:

`cp.cuda.get_current_stream().done` is True in the background thread immediately after the kernel has run but then can become False where I need to do the test despite my code not calling the GPU between the True and the False states. I haven't been able to explain this behaviour but I found I could not rely solely on stream_done. My testing suggests that: if stream_done is True at the point required then it is always safe to use the GPU; if stream_done is False it may or may not be safe to use the GPU.

I also have the background thread fire an event when it starts and stops, this event changes the worker_ready bool for the GUI thread. My testing showed worker_ready was more accurate for determining if the GPU could be used than stream_done. In cases where stream_done was True and worker_ready was False my testing showed the GPU code would also run quickly, presumably because the background thread was performing CPU code at that point in time.

So the best solution to the problem as I asked it was to use the GPU code if either condition is met. However even this didn't remove the visual lag I was seeking to eliminate.

The problem I was trying to solve was that when a background process is running on the GPU and the user tries to pan then occasionally there is a noticable lag of at least 0.5s. I attempted to quantify this lag by measuring the time from mouse press to the panned image being displayed. The time delay measured was 0.1s or less. Therefore no matter how fast the code is after the mouse click it cannot remove the lag whether using the GPU or the CPU.
To me this implies that the starting mouse press event itself has a delay in firing when the GPU is occupied. Presumably this is because the GPU is also running the display driver. I don't have any solid evidence of this beyond:

- If the background thread does not run then the lag is removed.
- Making the kernels orders of magnitude shorter did not reduce the lag at all.
- Increasing the block_size to move away from full occupancy seemed to remove the lag most of the time, although it did not eliminate it completely.